# How to get empty length of td:nth-child?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide columns which is completely empty. As you can see below table there is 4 column and 5 row in total. I want to hide column c3 beacuse there is no data in any cell. But i want to keep other columns because they have data. *(even some cells are empty)*

```
     c1     c2     c3    c4
     ----------------------
1    x      x            x        
2    x                   x
3                        x
4    x      x            x
5    x      x            x
```

How can i get empty row number for each td:nth-child to compare with total row numbers? So able to hide the empty columns?

Here is my code;

```
var rLenght = document.getElementById('table').rows.length;
var empty = ; // code for empty td:nth-child 

for (var i = 1; i<=4; i++) {
     var empty =              // code for empty td:nth-child('+i+')
            if (empty ==  rLenght) {
                $('td:nth-child('+i+'),th:nth-child('+i+')').hide();
            }
    }
```

Comment: This is unclear , you want to detect wich collumn are empty first? **and then** hide this column ?

Comment: I want to know how many empty rows in which column in table. When i get this result , if the total number of rows is equal to the number of empty rows, then that mean all rows in this column are empty. So i can hide this column.

Comment: there is no empty rows in your table, you mean **cells** instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Creating an array of found non-empty

```js
const cols = new Array(document.querySelectorAll("thead tr th").length-1)
  .fill(0);
document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr")
  .forEach(tr => tr.querySelectorAll("td")
    .forEach((td,i) => cols[i] += td.textContent.trim() !== ""))

document.querySelectorAll("tr").forEach(
  tr => tr.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(
    (td,i) => td.classList.toggle("hide",cols[i]===0)
  )
)
```

```css
.hide { display:none}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>c1</th>
      <th>c2</th>
      <th>c3</th>
      <th>c4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>x</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>x</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>4</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>5</th>
      <td>x</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Using the cols array instead should be faster

```js
const cols = new Array(document.querySelectorAll("#tb thead tr th").length)
  .fill(0);

document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr")
  .forEach(tr => tr.querySelectorAll("td, th")
    .forEach((td, i) => cols[i] += td.textContent.trim() === "" ? 0 : 1) // replace the 0 with number of cells with content
  )  

const rows = document.querySelectorAll("tr");
cols.forEach((col,i) => document.querySelectorAll("#tb tr")
  .forEach(tr => tr.querySelectorAll("td, th")[i].classList.toggle("hide", col === 0)));
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<table id="tb">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>c1</th>
      <th>c2</th>
      <th>c3</th>
      <th>c4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>x</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>x</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>4</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>5</th>
      <td>x</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Pagination

```js
const hide = () => {
  const cols = new Array(document.querySelectorAll("#tb thead tr th").length).fill(0);
  const tb = document.getElementById("tb")
  const bodyRows = tb.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");
  const rows = tb.querySelectorAll("tr");
  bodyRows.forEach(tr => tr.querySelectorAll("td, th")
    .forEach((td, i) => cols[i] += td.textContent.trim() === "" ? 0 : 1) // replace the 0 with number of cells with content
  )
  cols.forEach((col, i) => rows.forEach(tr => tr.querySelectorAll("td, th")[i].classList.toggle("hide", col === 0)));
};
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  tb.querySelector("tbody").innerHTML = page1;
  hide();
  document.getElementById("next").addEventListener("click", function() {
    tb.querySelector("tbody").innerHTML = page2;
    hide();
  })
})

const page1 = `<tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td></td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>4</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>5</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>`;
const page2 = `<tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>x</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>x</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>4</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>5</th>
      <td>x</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>`
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<table id="tb">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>c1</th>
      <th>c2</th>
      <th>c3</th>
      <th>c4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table><br/>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

Comment: @ErselÇakmak I found a faster solution using the cols array I made

Comment: Hi again. Now I'm trying to use this code in tables with pagination. But naturally it only works on the first page of the table. Is there any solution for pagination?

Comment: Why would it only work on the first page of the table?

Comment: I had accepted your answer, but I think I got it back with miss click, sorry for that. When the page loads, the first 10 records are listing in my table. After that without any page load, I can switch to page 2 or change the number of showing records and expand the table. For this reason when I switch the page all hidden columns are appears again.

Comment: See update. You need to hide every time you load new rows

Comment: It's worked perfectly. Thank you. You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Empty selector: https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/ maybe?

```js
var rLenght = document.getElementById('tbody').rows.length;

for (var i = 1; i<=4; i++) {
  var empty = $('td:nth-child('+i+'):empty');
  if (empty.length === rLenght) {
    $('td:nth-child('+i+'),th:nth-child('+i+')').hide();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>c1</th>
      <th>c2</th>
      <th>c3</th>
      <th>c4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody">
    <tr>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>x</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```